# Retrieving a Table Join Result Set from my REST API

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I've created a JHipster Monolithic application with the entities: profile, following & voyage which results in the following schema:

[image: Schema]

- I've extended JHI_USER by adding a PROFILE entity.
- Each User can Follow zero or more other Users (FOLLOWING).
- A user has zero or more Voyages (VOYAGES)

In my web Angular application I want to display a list of voyages for the users that a particular user is following.  The following SQL query will give me the required result set:

```
SELECT PROFILE.HANDLE, VOYAGE.NAME
FROM PROFILE, VOYAGE, FOLLOWING
WHERE FOLLOWING.USER_ID = 4
AND VOYAGE.USER_ID = PROFILE.USER_ID
AND PROFILE.USER_ID = FOLLOWING.FOLLOWING_ID
```

What are the steps required to create a REST endpoint in my JHipster application that returns this result set?

Do I need to do the following?

- Create a new Entity class for the result set
- Create a new Repository class that executes the query
- Create an endpoint in my Controller that calls the Repository to retrieve the result as a list of my entity

I'm new to Spring JPA and have been struggling to implement it.

=== Update ===

Here are the entity classes from my project:

The 'Profile' entity:

```
/**
 * A Profile.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "handle", nullable = false)
    private String handle;

    @Column(name = "bio")
    private String bio;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHandle() {
        return handle;
    }

    public Profile handle(String handle) {
        this.handle = handle;
        return this;
    }

    public void setHandle(String handle) {
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public Profile bio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
        return this;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Profile user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Profile profile = (Profile) o;
        if (profile.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, profile.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", handle='" + handle + "'" +
            ", bio='" + bio + "'" +
            '}';
    }
}
```

The 'Following' entity:

/**
     * A Following.
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "following")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Following implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private User following;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getFollowing() {
        return following;
    }

    public Following following(User user) {
        this.following = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setFollowing(User user) {
        this.following = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Following user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Following following = (Following) o;
        if (following.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, following.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Following{" +
            "id=" + id +
            '}';
    }
}
```

The 'Voyage' entity:

```
/**
 * A Voyage.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "voyage")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Voyage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "distance")
    private Integer distance;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Voyage name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public Voyage startDate(ZonedDateTime startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStartDate(ZonedDateTime startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public Voyage distance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
        return this;
    }

    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Voyage user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Voyage voyage = (Voyage) o;
        if (voyage.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, voyage.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Voyage{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + "'" +
            ", startDate='" + startDate + "'" +
            ", distance='" + distance + "'" +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: How did u add your entities ? manually or by using the generator ? if u used   the generator all f those things you mentioned are automatically generated for you Entity class ,repository, service, rest endpoint and angular crud interface

Comment: I used the generator.  The query I want to run doesn't map directly to any of the existing entities as it is a join of several tables and the result set returned has columns from both the Profile & Voyage entities.

Comment: So as I understand from your comment this is not Jhipster related, but rather spring-data one. You should read https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods and post the concrete entity classes if you need help creating the query since it is hard to answer your question just from UML

Comment: I've added the Entity classes to my original post.  Maybe the problem is the way I've structured the relationship between my entities.  Perhaps I should restructure so that the entities 'Following' & 'Voyage' have a One-to-Many relationship with 'Profile' (which is just an extension of JHI_USER), that way I can reference both 'Following' and 'Voyage' through the 'Profile' entity.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying your Schema as you suggested in your comment you will need to add 2 queries:

1.VoyageRepository:

```
List<Voyage> findByProfileIn(Collection<Profile> profiles);
```

2.ProfileRepository

```
List<Profile> findByFollowingID(long Id);
```

Then in your Voyage Service combine those 2 queries:

```
return voyageRepository.findByProfileIn(profileRepository.findbyFollowingId(id));
```

and then expose that in your VoyageRessource.

Comment: I modified the Schema, but I get `PropertyReferenceException: No property followingID found for type Profile! Did you mean 'followings'?` after adding `List<Profile> findByFollowingID(long Id);` to ProfileRepository.  Is this because the relationship between Profile & Following (One to Many) is unidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by:

1.Modifying the Schema so that the 'Profile' has a One-to-Many
    relationship with 'Following' & 'Voyage' i.e. removed the
    relationship between JHI_USER & 'Following' and 'Voyage'

2.Defining the following query within VoyageRepository

```
public interface VoyageRepository extends JpaRepository<Voyage,Long> {
    @Query("select v.name, v.profile.handle from Voyage v, Following f where f.profile.user.id = 4 and f.following.id = v.profile.id")

    List<Voyage> getFeed();
}
```

I've hardcoded the id value (4) in the above code as I haven't worked out how to pass in parameters to the query.  JPA is mind bending!

Comment: `@Query("select v.name, v.profile.handle from Voyage v, Following f where f.profile.user.id = :id and f.following.id = v.profile.id")    List<Voyage> getFeed(@Param(id) long id);`